# Use of Raspberry Pi 3 as a web server - is it a good choice?

Tags: pi-3, web-server, php, apache-httpd

Currently, I'm using a web hosting service and I spend about 33$/month.

I'm planning to buy Raspberry Pi 3 for have my own web server, but I'm worrying about performance.

Is it safe (regarding temperature, stability, speed) for Raspberry Pi 3 to handle 10 thousand concurrent connections with Apache + PHP + MySQL?

Comment: Do you mean 10 000 concurrent sessions?

Comment: There are some good options that you should explore like `heroku, openshift, a small orange` etc. Raspberry pi is not a good idea for hosting at all.

Comment: yeah I meant 10,000 concurrent sessions.

Comment: I won't even ask what these users are supposed to do. Just forget the idea.

Comment: Beyond the number of connections, you would have to be responsible for security, maintenance, the database etc. it is unlikely that you have a skillset on par with those whose job it is to do this - especially as it pertains to security. Ask yourself this how many users would you have after a security breach? How would you fend off a DDOS attack with a single Pi (ostensibly running through a home based router). Not to mention that your current provider likely has a highspeed (several times the size you have) connection to the internet.

Comment: With your traffic levels there are several options to monetize your site (ads etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> when raspberry pi 3 handles 10 Thousand connection

**Very, very unlikely.** If each connection were generating 1 KB/s of traffic, that's 10 MB/s, which is just within the 12 MB/s *theoretical upper limit* of the 100 Mbps ethernet NIC.

But I don't see how a 4 x 1.2 Ghz processor is going to be able to do much with that volume of information, besides maybe turn it around.  That's without starting to think about the overhead of just juggling all the connections.

Of course, 1 KB/s may be a high average. In any case you need to look closer at your requirements but if you are really talking about 10,000 concurrent connections, no matter what they are doing, a Pi 3 is not an appropriate solution.